# Kolmogorov’s example of a measurable function not (generally) differentiable

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory

In [1, page 7], the author says.

> Kolmogorov showed that if the function $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 3^n x}{3^n}$$ has a finite or infinite generalized derivative on a set of positive measure, then the function is *nonmeasurable*.

Where can I find a proof/explanation of this result (and/or other similar results) **in English**? The reference doesn't have to be to Kolmogorov's orignal paper; for example, a modern exposition would suffice (and might very well be better).

[1] A. N. Shiryaev, "Andrei Nikolaevich Kolmogorov", Theory of Probability
and Applications, vol 34, no. 1, 1988.

Note that I also posted [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86765/kolmogorovs-example-of-a-measurable-function-not-generally-differentiable). Since it's just a reference request, I don't think cross-posting is a big deal in this case.

Comment: If you have a proof in Russian, I can write its translation in English

Comment: The only one I have so far is in French: 'Sur la possibilite de la definition generale de la derivee, de l'integrale et de la sommation des series divergentes', C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris 180(1925), 362-364.

Comment: So you should rewrite your question as "Help me translate this French article"...

Comment: @Norbert I assume this work (or work including examples (with proof) of other such functions) should already exist in English. I'd rather look for that before I trouble someone with translating.

Comment: Are any of the answers on MathOverflow acceptable to you? If so, you might want to consider accepting one of them.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Done. Thanks.

Comment: @QuinnCulver: Would you mind copying the accepted answer into a CW answer to this question (with full attribution of course) so that this question will no longer be listed as unanswered?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Naaaaaaaaaw. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/86765/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Raymond Manzoni below.

> A translation in english is in "Selected Works of A.N. Kolmogorov I" : ["On the possibility of a general definition of derivative, integral and summation of divergent series"](http://books.google.fr/books?id=ikN59GkYJKIC&pg=PA33)  (page 33 and 34).